# Tuscany and JMS binding:URI must start with the scheme jms:

Tags: java, jms, sca, apache-tuscany

I am using Tuscany 1.6.2 and I try to run the hello-world service JMS example, but
deployed in a node in the domain manager. That means, I start the
domain manager, register the helloworld-service-jms.jar as a
contribution, register the composite, register a node for the
composite.
Now I should be able to start the node, but during start, the
following message pops up:

INFO: SEVERE: URI must start with the scheme jms: for uri:
/HelloWorldServiceComponent
…
INFO: SEVERE: SCA Node could not be created

I have another project, which uses this jms binding and it works, if I
start the node via code, e.g. using this method:
nodeFactory.createSCANode…
and node.start()

(but if I deploy it using the domain manager, same error occurs)
what am i doing wrong or is this a bug or something?!
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i will answer my own tumbleweed-question ;)
it was actually a bug in tuscany 1.x.x as i think, which leads to wrong resolution of the jms binding (more informations [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tuscany-user/201206.mbox/%3CCAAF0_MzmCgr+b8FDD0EBM0diPx1PmmeqGMLPCY2VHwvNRHQWuw@mail.gmail.com%3E))